# Docker Exiting Automatically

Tags: docker

I am currently learning docker and following this tutorial.

http://containertutorials.com/alpine/alpine-apache-server-static-site.html

I have follow all the steps but the docker container keeps exiting within a few seconds. Here is the log,

```
[s6-init] making user provided files available at 
/var/run/s6/etc...exited 0.
[s6-init] ensuring user provided files have correct perms...exited 0.
[fix-attrs.d] applying ownership & permissions fixes...
[fix-attrs.d] done.
[cont-init.d] executing container initialization scripts...
[cont-init.d] 30-resolver: executing... 
[cont-init.d] 30-resolver: exited 0.
[cont-init.d] 40-resolver: executing... 
[cont-init.d] 40-resolver: exited 0.
[cont-init.d] done.
[services.d] starting services
[services.d] done.
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified 
domain name, using 172.17.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to 
suppress this message
[cont-finish.d] executing container finish scripts...
[cont-finish.d] done.
[s6-finish] syncing disks.
[s6-finish] sending all processes the TERM signal.
[s6-finish] sending all processes the KILL signal and exiting.
```

Am I missing something?

(I am also running this in ubuntu, not sure if this helps.)

Comment: Did you try setting the ServerName directive globally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the tutorial, got the same error. Seems like a problem with the source image from smebberson/alpine-apache.

Solve your problem by not solving your problem: find another tutorial (using another image) to learn with. Don't lose sleep over this particular tutorial!